# Alternating axis line colors in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am using D3 (v4) and attempting to create a X axis with alternating color bars in between each tick. This is what I'm trying to mimic:

[image]

Currently I have an X axis with ticks at every hour like I want.

```
const hoursBarAxis = axisBottom(this.xScale)
  .ticks(timeHour, 1)
  .tickSize(5)
  .tickPadding(36)
  .tickFormat('');

this.graph.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.xOffset + ',' + height + ')')
      .call(hoursBarAxis);
```

Which looks like this:
[image]

**FIRST ATTEMPT:**
Did something similar to this example: https://codepen.io/idan/pen/xejuD

I insert a rect after each tick to essentially draw a rect in between each tick mark (alternating purple and gray below). This got me very close to my desired outcome but my dilemma then became handling the beginning and the end of the axis (the part before the first tick and the fact that the rect after the last tick was too long).

[image]

**OTHER ATTEMPTS:**
I've tried numerous other methods of adding one piece of the axis at time and various CSS hacks to append items after ticks but none of them worked or solved my problem correctly.

So my question is...is there an easier way to solve this problem that I'm not seeing? Focusing on altering the ticks seems to be the wrong idea because that doesn't handle the initial piece before the first tick.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, we are tempted to use an easy solution which relies on the fact that the axis generator creates an structure like this for each tick (don't mind the values, just the structure):

```
<g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(66.5,0)">
    <line stroke="#000" y2="6">
    </line><text fill="#000" y="9" dy="0.71em">10</text>
</g>
```

So, we can use those `<lines>` and `getBoundingClientRect()` to append our rectangles. For that, we will use an `each()` in the axis group.

The first step if checking if the tick has a next tick, since there will be no rectangle after the last one:

```
if (this.nextSibling) {
```

Then, we use this math to append the rectangles:

```
d3.select(this).append("rect")
    .attr("width", this.nextSibling.firstChild.getBoundingClientRect().x -
        this.firstChild.getBoundingClientRect().x)
    .attr("height", 6)
    .style("fill", i % 2 ? "green" : "red");
```

In this example, I'm using the indices of the ticks to paint the rectangles either "green" or "red". Note: that magic number `6` is just the default height of the tick in D3. change it accordingly.

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([20, 480]);
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale);
var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis);
gX.selectAll(".tick").each(function(d, i) {
  if (this.nextSibling) {
    d3.select(this).append("rect")
      .attr("width", this.nextSibling.firstChild.getBoundingClientRect().x - this.firstChild.getBoundingClientRect().x)
      .attr("height", 6)
      .style("fill", i % 2 ? "green" : "red");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

However, in your case, this won't work. Why?

According to your image, your problem is the first and last ticks. And here is the explanation: those are not ticks. Those "lines" belong to the path that creates the horizontal line in the axis.

We can clearly see this if we change the domain a little bit, have a look:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([5, 105])
  .range([20, 480]);
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale);
var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis);
gX.selectAll(".tick").each(function(d, i) {
  if (this.nextSibling) {
    d3.select(this).append("rect")
      .attr("width", this.nextSibling.firstChild.getBoundingClientRect().x - this.firstChild.getBoundingClientRect().x)
      .attr("height", 6)
      .style("fill", i % 2 ? "green" : "red");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

So, how to deal with that?

**Solution**: convert those "false" ticks to "real" thicks. This can be done using `tickValues`:

```
.tickValues(scale.ticks().concat(scale.domain()));
```

As an additional complication, we have to sort the ticks after that:

```
gX.selectAll(".tick").sort(function(a, b) {
  return d3.ascending(a, b);
});
```

And here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([5, 105])
  .range([20, 480]);
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickValues(scale.ticks().concat(scale.domain()))
  .tickFormat(function(d,i,n){
    return i === n.length - 1 || i === n.length - 2 ? null : d; 
  });
var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis);
gX.selectAll(".tick").sort(function(a, b) {
  return d3.ascending(a, b);
});
gX.selectAll(".tick").each(function(d, i) {
  if (this.nextSibling) {
    d3.select(this).append("rect")
      .attr("width", this.nextSibling.firstChild.getBoundingClientRect().x - this.firstChild.getBoundingClientRect().x)
      .attr("height", 6)
      .style("fill", i % 2 ? "green" : "red");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

Comment: This did it for me, thanks!

I did have to make one small change because mine is a UTC (time) scale and I needed ticks on every hour. So in case anyone is interested:
`.tickValues(this.xScale.ticks(timeHour, 1).concat(this.xScale.domain()))`